# Finding percentile rank.

Tags: percentile

The problem goes:

Given the following table bellow:

\begin{array}{|l|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\textbf{Data}      & -10 & 25 & 37 & 40 & 43 & 54 & 111 & 113 & 146 & 168 \\ \hline
\textbf{Frequency} & 3   & 6  & 1  & 5  & 3  & 2  & 7   & 5   & 3   & 4   \\ \hline
\end{array}

Using the data from the table above, find the percentile rank for the $54$.

I know percentile rank is  #below the total #.  Which,  in this case  is $18$ over $39$ which will equal to $46$ percentile ( I know this because the answer and how to solve the problem was giving to me as a practice test)  but my question is  where did that $18$ over $39$ comes from? How do I get those number?

Answer (score 1):

You have $18$ from $39$ results less than $54$, so the percentile is $\frac{18}{39}$ . It is equal to the ratio of outcomes below $54$.